# Flex: lexical analyzer to remove multicomment line in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, comments, flex-lexer

I have the follow code :

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
%}

%x multicomment

%option noyywrap
%% 

--(.*) ; 
  
"{-"      BEGIN(multicomment);
<multicomment>[^*\n]+    
<multicomment>"*"        
<multicomment>\n         
<multicomment>"-}"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
%% 
  
int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
    yyin=fopen("Code.txt","r"); 
    yyout=fopen("out.c","w");

    yylex(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The task to achievement is pretty simple... remove single/multiline comment from an haskell code.

--    for single line;
{- -} for multiline;

The code above works fine if I use **"/*"** & **"*/"** (for C comment) instead of **"{-"** & **"-}"**. When I use the last two, I don't know why flex removes all other characters after {-.

Example, suppose to have the following input text to clean:

> ```
> some text
>
> {- some other text
>     in multiline
>     with haskel comment
> -}
>
> /* another text
>     always in multiline
>     but with C comment
> */
>
> some text without comment
> ```

If the above code is setted as follow:

```
    "/*"      BEGIN(multicomment);
    <multicomment>[^*\n]+    
    <multicomment>"*"        
    <multicomment>\n         
    <multicomment>"*/"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

with **/*"** & **"*/"** output is right:

> ```
> some text
>
> {- some other text
>     in multiline
>     with haskel comment initiator
> -}
>
> some text without comment
> ```

Instead if I use the original code

```
    "{-"      BEGIN(multicomment);
    <multicomment>[^*\n]+    
    <multicomment>"*"        
    <multicomment>\n         
    <multicomment>"-}"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

with **"{-"** & **"-}"**, It doesn't work and the output is:

> some text

It delete all characters from **"{-"** until the end of file, I've also tried other setups recommended in other forums as:

```
<multicomment>"-\}"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
<multicomment>"-"+"}"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
<multicomment>"-" + "}"    BEGIN(INITIAL);
<multicomment>[-}]    BEGIN(INITIAL);
```

But in these cases when i try to compile with **flex CommentClean.l**, this is the result:

> CommentClean.l:16: warning, rule cannot be matched

Can someone help me? Where I'am wrong? How can I do?

Comment: You cannot accurately remove comments unless you recognize string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve only changed the beginning and ending delimiters, but not the rules to match the *contents*.

The original rules say “in the `multicomment` state, ignore one or more non-asterisks and newlines; ignore a single asterisk; and ignore a newline”. An asterisk followed by a slash is matched as the ending delimiter by the longest-match rule.

```
    <multicomment>[^*\n]+    
    <multicomment>"*"        
    <multicomment>\n
```

What was happening in your code when you only changed the delimiters is that `{-` would begin a comment, and then the closing delimiter `-}` would be consumed as part of the contents, “a series of non-asterisk/newline characters”, which will win because it matches a (much!) longer string.

I think you just need to change the asterisks to hyphens:

```
    <multicomment>[^-\n]+    
    <multicomment>"-"        
    <multicomment>\n
```

However, note that this doesn’t account for the fact that in Haskell, unlike in C, multi-line comments may be *nested* like so:

```
{-

a multi-line comment

  {-
    containing another comment

    {- containing yet another comment -}

  -}

-}
```

So to be strictly correct, you should also include a rule that matches multi-line comments recursively. Also bear in mind that `--` is only a single-line comment if not part of an operator, so for example `-->` and `|--` are valid operators, not the start of a comment. (And yes, people use these in real code!)

You can find the specification for comments in the [Haskell Report §2.3](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-170002.3). It says that a symbol is:

- Any one of these characters (*ascSymbol*): `!` `#` `$` `%` `&` `⋆` `+` `.` `/` `<` `=` `>` `?` `@` `\` `^` `|` `-` `~` `:`; or
- Any Unicode character with the properties Symbol (S) or Punctuation (P) (*uniSymbol*), except for `(` `)` `,` `;` `[` `]` `` ` `` `{` `}` (*special*) and `_` `"` `'`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved! It was exactly change from asterisk to hyphen. I know that comments can be nested, but this will be next achievent.